# Async mode with acks = all

Tags: apache-kafka

I am seeing a different behavior with acks all. From the documentation,

> acks=all This means the leader will wait for the full set of in-sync
> replicas to acknowledge the record. This guarantees that the record
> will not be lost as long as at least one in-sync replica remains
> alive. This is the strongest available guarantee. This is equivalent
> to the acks=-1 setting.

I had a 3 broker setup and a topic with replication factor 3 .My understaning about the above statement is , the leader *will wait* if any of the brokers is down( as it *will wait for ISR to acknowledge * the record. But, to my surprise, it is the not the case, the message is produced and consumed by the consumer.

Is it that, it is not *honored* in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acks = all is honored in relation to the min.insync.replicas broker parameter that by default is 1; this is the reason why you see your producer sending without problems and the consumer consuming as well.
In your case, with 3 brokers, if you want the producer be able to send only when ALL of them are running, you have to set min.insync.replicas=3 as well.

Comment: hmm, I am wondering if we look at only acks = all, it will add up confusion as "all" might refer to all replicas. We need to interpret this along with "min.insync.replicas", to really how much "all" is :-))

Comment: yeah it could be confusing, I agree but it is what it is :-)

Comment: do you know if there is any "particular" reason, the documentation didnt have any mention about "min.insync.replicas" in the description about "Acks=all"  - acks=all This means the leader will wait for the full set of in-sync replicas to acknowledge the record. This guarantees that the record will not be lost as long as at least one in-sync replica remains alive. This is the strongest available guarantee. This is equivalent to the acks=-1 setting.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this need to be interpreted along with *min.insync.replicas* .

> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), min.insync.replicas
> specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write
> for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be
> met, then the producer will raise an exception (either
> NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend). When used
> together, min.insync.replicas and acks allow you to enforce greater
> durability guarantees.